# Chrome adding gray outline to printed transparent png/gif

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, printing

I'm working on a printing template in the browser for print-to-pdf, and am using a transparent .png overlay in one section.

**This happens both with transparent .png files and transparent .gif files**:

Chrome, when printing (both to .pdf, and in the print preview window), seems to outline transparent images with a 1px gray line:

**Exhibit A:**

[image]

I've tried this in several other browsers (including Safari) and none appear to do what Chrome does. Has anyone seen this before? I need to find a way to disable it or hack it on the Chrome side so that this will work across browsers.

To see this in action, click here: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonscript/nELwd/ (just an `<img />` tag) and press Cmd/Ctrl+P to bring up the print preview. You'll see this in the preview *and* if you print to .pdf. Make sure you have "Background colors and images" enabled, or you won't see any images.

**Note:** I'm not looking for workarounds *after* it's been printed and I'm aware that if you size the image to 100% and view the .pdf at 100% zoom you don't see the gray line. I need to programmatically (or otherwise) *remove* the gray line prior to printing the .pdf.

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this on Chrome in Windows.

Comment: @admdrew I tried this on 30.0.1599.101 for Mac and 29.0.1547.76 for Windows, both are doing this. What version of Chrome on Win are you using?

Comment: I see an outline in print preview in Version 30.0.1599.101 m on Win7/64.

Comment: I get the impression that the file is being converted to 8-bit. Is the gray stroke the same color as the original image's background/matte?

Comment: @isherwood I've tried this with .pngs too - I've updated the `img` jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/remus/nELwd/1/ to show both. There's no matte on the png, and the gif's matte is white. Interesting thought about 8-bit, but why on earth would Chrome do that?

Comment: @r3mus Actually, I remembered I'm using Chromium (29.0.1524.0 (203139)), so maybe that's it. Sorry :/

Comment: Not much use here, but I've tried making it a background-image too, and that didn't fix it either: http://jsfiddle.net/nELwd/2/. Seems to me it might be a bug and worth reporting? It looks like there are several similar ones: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=225732 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177651 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226972

Comment: @yochannah indeed, I came across those same bugs - hoping still to get this resolve here, but if no one knows anything, I'll file a bug.

Comment: Even if you can find a fix/workaround, it's probably still a bug... ;)

Comment: Submitted a bug report last night, guess we'll see if it goes anywhere. I'll keep an eye out if they fix it and update this post.

Comment: the chrome is showing the casing of your image because it contains white edges and I think it's what makes the error appears, just put transparency in your image which I believe will work

Comment: @PauloLima it is a transparent image; take a look at it if you like. Tried it with a .gif too, same deal.

Comment: because I think not, since I put your picture on a page with a color in the background and he pemaneceu white

Comment: @PauloLima I don't think you're understanding the problem. The image has a gray outline around it if you try and print. This doesn't occur in other browsers like Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experimented enough and considered all the answers above while doing so. 
Suspiciously, Upon saving your image and opening in gimp and some pokes into it, What I found was this.

[image: the original image,] [image: Wiped the empty white space around the image...]

Which makes me think that **your image in truth, containing the gray border around it.** My suggestion is you remove that layer and make that empty space around the actual image to transparent.

**EDIT**(response to @remus comment)

I do not know if my claim is correct, but I am believing that the image is not what you are expecting it to be. You need to correct that image. I have tested with `another image of mine`, [pasted on the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sivatumma/m9GjZ/) is not having any border around it in screen and print preview. (And the final pdf too). Sorry if this Answer is correct and hurts you.

Comment: I wish it were that simple, but you can try this with any transparent .png or .gif and it does it in Chrome. But the same original image doesn't in Safari.

Comment: Indeed, that's the closest I've seen to a workaround! I've tried several images, but yours doesn't do it. I'll have to play around; thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't come across this exact issue, I do a lot of work with css printing (for pdf and browser printing) and more often than not I have to use 2 images: 1 for screen and 1 for printing (do not use transparency for the printing one in yuour case):

```
<img src='http://apigee.ignite.ms/iloveapis/portal/badge/heart-overlay.gif' width='300' height='400' class="screen"/>

<img src='http://apigee.ignite.ms/iloveapis/portal/badge/heart-overlay_print.gif' width='300' height='400' class="forPrinting"/>
```

in your main css file:

```
img.forPrinting { display:none }
```

in your print css file which should be declared after your main css file:

```
img.screen {display:none }
img.forPrinting { display:block; }
```

Comment: Sadly in the context of this situation, there are multiple images layered on top of each other dynamically, then I'm generating a pdf with fpdf based on that. Images have to stay transparent in the printing process.

Answer (score -1):

Short Answer:
Change your PDF printing preset to a higher resolution.

you'll get:
[image]

The Long version:

I noticed you have re-sized the image by changing its width height properties in the HTML code.
So I made sure your image is exactly in the size you need it and it will not have this strange contour.

See Link: jsfiddle.net/cyVqw/

I have a print preview:[image: Print Preview]

PDF screenshot:

[image: PDF Screenshot]

To verify that in any size the PDF will keep your image transparency I checked 
PDF saved in a Higher resolution preset i.e. "Print Quality". this resulted in a large file but with better zooming quality:

Here is High Resolution 33% preview:

[image: High Resolution 33% preview]

High Resolution 200% preview

[image: High Resolution 200% preview]

So, what you need to do is to adjust your PDF quality preset.

Comment: Not true at all. Did you actually test that before answering... ?

Comment: If you take that jsFiddle and remove the width/height from the HTML it still shows up. It doesn't do that in Safari or Firefox.

Comment: your image is very large. make it in the exact size. see http://jsfiddle.net/cyVqw/

Comment: If you change the zoom in the PDF viewer you'll get the contour again, since the image object in the PDF will be re-sized without anti-aliasing. 100% will show ok.

Comment: Ah, yes keeping the image at 100% in the PDF doesn't show it, but since a PDF is rarely viewed at exactly 100%, that's much much of a solution. Workaround at best, but doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: PDF saves your GIF part and zoom in/out manipulates the image grammatically if you change the PDF printer preset to higher resolution i.e. press quality, you will not have such problems. lower resolution PDF preset will give you bad re-sizing capabilities.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question - I'm not looking for workarounds, I'm looking to find out how to either fix this problem in Chrome or at least identify what's causing it. So far my workaround has been to make non-transparent images and it works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel this way, but your problem is not chrome. its the PDF printing preset. just set it to a higher resolution.

Comment: If it's not Chrome, then why does this not reproduce in Safari, Firefox, or even IE10? Moreover, since I'm the one asking the question, and I'm the one who set the bounty, I'm allowed to dictate the conditions of a valid answer.

Comment: Dragging the image in all browsers resulted in the same jugged gif.

Comment: A resized GIF will always be jugged. The question is not how each browser is implementing a GIF's resize or scaing, with or without smart anti-aliasing. browsers are not photoshop. The question indicated a problem in the print preview and the resulting PDF. I think I showed you that if you change your PDF preset to a higher quality the result is a PDF without any contour around the gif. check it for yourself. Now if you excuse me, I have to go. Have fun PDF-ing ;)